# Extracting text from an image with tesseract

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, tesseract

I'm using tesseract to extract text from an image. However, there are some problems I'm running into with certain images:

The text is extracted perfectly fine from the image below:

[image]

However, the text is not extracted from the image below, note that the square around the text is smaller now

[image]

**Questions**

what are some things I can do to the original image to better extract the text from the second image. I am already making the image BW usint imagemagick's `-monochrome` filter.

In the images I do not care about anything but the text. Is there a technique I can use to crop the image and make a new image with nothing but white background and text? I won't always know the coordinates for the square circle so I would need a cropping function that would automatically detect the co-ordinates of white background..

Comment: I think I gave a very detailed answer on your other question (which is remarkably similar to this one). Take a look and let me know if it's sufficient.