# How to determine a region of interest and then crop an image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, python, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690770/extracting-text-from-an-image-with-tesseract) but that is focused more on tesseract.

I have a sample image as below. I would like to make the white square my Region of Interest and then crop out that part (square) and create a new image with it. I will be working with different images so the square won't always be at the same location in all images. So I will need to somehow detect the edges of the square.

[image]

What are some pre-processing methods I can perform to achieve the result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using your test image I was able to **remove all the noises with a simple [erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode)** operation.

[image]

After that, **a simple iteration on the `Mat` to find for the corner pixels** is trivial, and I talked about that on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317919/176769). For testing purposes we can draw *green* lines between those points to display the area we are interested at in the original image:

[image]

At the end, I **set the ROI in the original image and crop** out that part.

The final result is displayed on the image below:

[image]

I wrote a sample code that performs this task using the **C++ interface** of OpenCV. I'm confident in your skills to translate this code to Python. If you can't do it, forget the code and stick with the [roadmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_roadmap) I shared on this answer.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    std::cout << "Original image size: " << img.size() << std::endl;

    // Convert RGB Mat to GRAY
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    std::cout << "Gray image size: " << gray.size() << std::endl;

    // Erode image to remove unwanted noises
    int erosion_size = 5;
    cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS,
                                       cv::Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
                                       cv::Point(erosion_size, erosion_size) );
    cv::erode(gray, gray, element);

    // Scan the image searching for points and store them in a vector
    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = gray.begin<uchar>();
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = gray.end<uchar>();
    for (; it != end; it++)
    {
        if (*it) 
            points.push_back(it.pos()); 
    }

    // From the points, figure out the size of the ROI
    int left, right, top, bottom;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) // initialize corner values
        {
            left = right = points[i].x;
            top = bottom = points[i].y;
        }

        if (points[i].x < left)
            left = points[i].x;

        if (points[i].x > right)
            right = points[i].x;

        if (points[i].y < top)
            top = points[i].y;

        if (points[i].y > bottom)
            bottom = points[i].y;
    }
    std::vector<cv::Point> box_points;
    box_points.push_back(cv::Point(left, top));
    box_points.push_back(cv::Point(left, bottom));
    box_points.push_back(cv::Point(right, bottom));
    box_points.push_back(cv::Point(right, top));

    // Compute minimal bounding box for the ROI
    // Note: for some unknown reason, width/height of the box are switched.
    cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(box_points));
    std::cout << "box w:" << box.size.width << " h:" << box.size.height << std::endl;

    // Draw bounding box in the original image (debugging purposes)
    //cv::Point2f vertices[4];
    //box.points(vertices);
    //for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    //{
    //    cv::line(img, vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % 4], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, CV_AA);
    //}
    //cv::imshow("Original", img);
    //cv::waitKey(0);

    // Set the ROI to the area defined by the box
    // Note: because the width/height of the box are switched, 
    // they were switched manually in the code below:
    cv::Rect roi;
    roi.x = box.center.x - (box.size.height / 2);
    roi.y = box.center.y - (box.size.width / 2);
    roi.width = box.size.height;
    roi.height = box.size.width;
    std::cout << "roi @ " << roi.x << "," << roi.y << " " << roi.width << "x" << roi.height << std::endl;

    // Crop the original image to the defined ROI
    cv::Mat crop = img(roi);

    // Display cropped ROI
    cv::imshow("Cropped ROI", crop);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am currently trying to convert the C code you provided to JavaCV :). Thanks again.

Comment: No need to thank me, just up vote the answer. Consider clicking on the checkbox near it to select it as the official answer. By doing these things you will be helping future visitors.

Comment: what does the line `if (*it)` do/stand for?

Comment: I am really confused. I put a if/else block on that line of code. i.e. `if (*it) { std::cout << "if" << std::endl; std::cout << it.pos() << std::endl; } else { std::cout << "else" << std::endl; std::cout << it.pos() << std::endl; }` but for example I get the following in the output `if [411, 280] else [412, 280]`. What is the difference in the two? points are not 0 in either of them..

Comment: You are printing the pixel coordinates, and I'm talking about the color of the pixel.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused because the `Mat` class in Java bindings have no such method that returns a byte that representing a pixels color

Comment: Perfect for some images. But some images give me an error like that:

Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat

Comment: That means that you are passing weird values for a ROI. This would happen if you are setting a ROI bigger than the image.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing that the text is the only large blob, and everything else is barely larger than a pixel, a simple morphological opening should suffice

You can do this [in opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html#opening)
or [with imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#open)

Afterwards the white rectangle should be the only thing left in the image. You can find it with opencvs findcontours, with the CvBlobs library for opencv or with the imagemagick -crop function

Here is your image with 2 steps of erosion followed by 2 steps of dilation applied:
[image]
You can simply plug this image into the opencv findContours function as in the [Squares tutorial example](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/squares.cpp?rev=4244) to get the position

Comment: This will work for detecting the square, however, the resulting image you provided blurs the text. I would like the text inside the square to remain as is because finally i would like to feed that text to an OCR. Please let me know if there are better ways to achieve what I'm trying to do

Comment: When you have got rectangle (even not filled) it's quite easy - use findContours function(http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) to find the contour of rectangle(probably you will find more than one contour - just take the biggest one) and then fill it with white color. You will have filled rectangle, so now just use bitwise and(http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) on this image and on original picture.

Answer (score 0):

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m350D.jpg)

```
#objective:
#1)compress large images to less than 1000x1000
#2)identify region of interests
#3)save rois in top to bottom order
import cv2
import os

def get_contour_precedence(contour, cols):
    tolerance_factor = 10
    origin = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    return ((origin[1] // tolerance_factor) * tolerance_factor) * cols + origin[0]

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('./images/sample_0.jpg')

#compress the image if image size is >than 1000x1000
height, width, color = image.shape #unpacking tuple (height, width, colour) returned by image.shape
while(width > 1000):
    height = height/2
    width = width/2
print(int(height), int(width))
height = int(height)
width = int(width)
image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9,9), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,30)
# Dilate to combine adjacent text contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
ret,thresh3 = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)

# Find contours, highlight text areas, and extract ROIs
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh3, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

#ORDER CONTOURS top to bottom
cnts.sort(key=lambda x:get_contour_precedence(x, image.shape[1]))

#delete previous roi images in folder roi to avoid
dir = './roi/'
for f in os.listdir(dir):
    os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 10000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        #cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (100,100,100), 1)
        #use below code to write roi when results are good
        ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('roi/ROI_{}.jpg'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[roi detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbaFI.jpg)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZXTr.jpg)