# Looping through OpenCV Mat in Java bindings

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am trying to convert a C++ method from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699181/131194) I received using OpenCV to Java using OpenCV Java bindings

C++ code:

```
cv::Mat gray;
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS,
                                       cv::Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
                                       cv::Point(erosion_size, erosion_size) );
cv::erode(gray, gray, element);
 // Scan the image searching for points and store them in a vector
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = gray.begin<uchar>();
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = gray.end<uchar>();
for (; it != end; it++)
{
    if (*it) 
        points.push_back(it.pos()); 
}
```

I can't figure out how to loop through the `gray` variable as they are in C code. Below is what I've got so far:

Java Code:

```
Mat gray = new Mat();
Mat element = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(
                Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1), new Point(erosion_size, erosion_size)
        );
Imgproc.erode(img, gray, element);
List <Point> p = new ArrayList<Point>();
//How to loop through the gray variable?
```

I went through the [API's](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) and it seems that `Mat` does have methods for getting `rows` and `cols` but I can't call `Iterator` on anything..

Comment: Like I told you before, use JavaCV.

Comment: @syb0rg It looks like you deleted your answer before.  Don't get spooked by a downvote.  It comes with the territory.

Comment: @DrewDormann I didn't get spooked, it got down-voted and another answer was accepted, meaning the OP didn't listen to my advice. It would make their life a lot easier if they would though...

Comment: @syb0rg I tried gown down the route of JavaCV however, it doesn't have some methods I want. for example `getStructuringElement`. Maybe they have a different name for that method but i was not able to find it. After going through that pain I decided to give OpenCV java bindings a try since they have a 1 to 1 matching with C functions at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Mat` is truly *gray*, it's probably of type `CV_8U`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gray.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gray.cols; j++)
    {
        byte pixel = gray.get(i, j);
    }
}
```

I don't have my environment setup to test this code. For more info check [this thread](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5/how-to-get-and-modify-the-pixel-of-mat-in-java/?answer=8#post-id-8).

If you are using **JavaCV**, some time ago I wrote a code to iterate on the pixels of a colored image and convert it to grayscale like this:

```
    IplImage imageSrc = cvLoadImage("pipeline.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (imageSrc == null) 
    {
        System.out.println("!!! Failed loading image");
        return;
    }

    double r, g, b;
    r = g = b = 0.0;               

    IplImage imageDst = IplImage.create(imageSrc.width(), imageSrc.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    CvMat imagePixels = CvMat.createHeader(imageDst.height(), imageDst.width(), CV_32FC1);  
    cvGetMat(imageDst, imagePixels, null, 0); 
    int x, y;
    for(y=0; y<imageSrc.height(); y++)
       for(x=0; x<imageSrc.width(); x++)
       {
            CvScalar rgb = cvGet2D(imagePixels, y, x);
            r = rgb.val(0);
            g = rgb.val(2);
            b = rgb.val(1);

            double gray = (r + g + b) / 3;

            CvScalar scalar = new CvScalar();
            scalar.setVal(0, gray);
            scalar.setVal(1, gray);
            scalar.setVal(2, gray);
           cvSet2D(imagePixels, y, x, scalar);
       }
       imageDst = new IplImage(imagePixels);  

       IplImage result = new IplImage(imagePixels); 
       cvSaveImage("manual_gray.png", result);

       cvReleaseImage(imageSrc);
```

Comment: @karlphillip  can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204124/how-to-iterate-in-opencv4android similar to this one.