# imagemagick - remove logo in image or crop image

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I have a [logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBL2V.jpg) and images which include that logo in corners like [top-left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hpj9.jpg), bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right.

Using imagemagick, how can I

(a) remove that logo OR

(b) if not possible, to find the logo it it's x/y coords and crop that image and cut the logo out?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is the logo the same size in all of the pictures? I take it which corner it lands in is random... ?

Comment: no, it's not the same size (logo and main images), and yes, the logo is placed randomly in the corners.

Comment: Out of interest are these your images you are removing the logo from?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question whether the logo appears always at the same size in your *"watermarked"* images.

If the size of the logo is known, you can do a sub-image search and fill or blur over or crop the logo.

If the size of the logo is variable, or unknown, you would need to look for a package (maybe **OpenCV**) which has *Scale Invariant* (**SIFT**) functionality which is not present AFAIK in **ImageMagick**.

Comment: the size is different though.

Comment: See the final paragraph of my answer then.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea how to do that using bash/command line? It looks good here but I really want to remove it or crop it. No evidence should be left ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125281/removing-watermark-out-of-an-image-using-opencv