# How to remove watermark background in image Python

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I have a image like below,

[image]

I would like to remove background watermark.

So far I tried, `inpainting` method in `opencv`. It didn't help me.

I tried following script:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
dst = cv2.inpaint(img,edges,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

I am new to image processing and `opencv`. So, I don't know whether I'm doing in the correct way or not for performing inpainting. What method should I do for removing background watermarks.

I would like to remove green quoted watermark from my image.

[image]

any help would be more appreciable.

Comment: http://davidsteccieblog.blogspot.com/2017/10/removing-watermarks.html

Comment: @jspcal - Thanks for your comment. I'll get back with you once I tried your recommended blog.

Comment: @jspcal - It didn't work for me :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32125281/2286337

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Text here has a different intensity than the watermark. You could play around with a simple brightness/contrast transformation, i.e. increasing gain/contrast until the watermark vanishes and reducing brightness to compensate.

See [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html) for a simple tutorial.

Here's a quick attempt in Python, not really using `OpenCV` because it's not needed IMHO for such a simple linear transformation. Play around with `alpha` (contrast) and `beta` (brightness) parameters until you get the result you want

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("veidz.jpg")

alpha = 2.0
beta = -160

new = alpha * img + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("cleaned.png", new)
```

[image: removed watermark]

Comment: This approach works for basic texts on white background , what if there are color images with colour watermark, i tried playing with contrast and brightness but no luck, it is just distorting the images. Can you highlight any other algorithm which can do that

Comment: this was never intended as a general method to remove watermarks, it was more to say that sometimes in image processing and computer vision the simplest transformations can take you a long way...

Comment: I need example that can help to remove watermarks from image, can you help me plz @filippo