# Is there a better way to separate the writing from the background?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, image-thresholding

I am working on a project where I should apply and OCR on some documents.
The first step is to threshold the image and let only the writing (whiten the background).

**Example of an input image:** (*For the GDPR and privacy reasons, this image is from the Internet*)

[image]
**Here is my code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread('b.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h = image.shape[0]
w = image.shape[1]
for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        if image[y, x] >= 120:
            image[y, x] = 255
        else:
            image[y, x] = 0
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image)
```

**Here is the result that I got:**

[image]

When I applied *pytesseract* to the output image, the results were not satisfying (I know that an OCR is not perfect). Although I tried to adjust the threshold value (in this code it is equal to 120), the result was not as clear as I wanted.

**Is there a way to make a better threshold in order to only keep the writing in black and whiten the rest?**

Comment: Its not a good idea to post your personal/someone ID online.

Comment: Thank you, I am totally aware of that, it is an image I downloaded from the Internet

Comment: The bottom part looks pretty clean, is that what you're trying to decode?

Comment: @MarkRansom, not only the bottom. Mainly the name, family name, date and place of birth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [adaptive thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptiveThreshold). From documentation :

> In this, the algorithm calculate the threshold for a small regions of the image. So we get different thresholds for different regions of the same image and it gives us better results for images with varying illumination.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2



image = cv2.imread('b.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.medianBlur(image ,5)

th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
cv2.imwrite('output1.jpg', th1 )
cv2.imwrite('output2.jpg', th2 )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't give a better result too: the background is still noisy so that the writing is not clear yet.

Comment: you need to change the last two parameters of `adaptiveThreshold` method accordingly in order to get better results

Comment: In fact, I tried to adjust the parameters, but it didn't give a good result.

Answer (score 3):

After digging deep in Stack**Overflow** questions, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50800425/8128190) which is about removing watermark using opencv.
I adapted the code to my needs and this is what I got:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('a.png')
img = image.copy()

alpha =2.75
beta = -160.0

denoised = alpha * img + beta
denoised = np.clip(denoised, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

#denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(denoised, None, 31, 7, 21)

img = cv2.cvtColor(denoised, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

h = img.shape[0]
w = img.shape[1]

for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        if img[y, x] >= 220:
            img[y, x] = 255
        else:
            img[y, x] = 0

cv2.imwrite('outpu.jpg', img)
```

Here is the output image:

[image]

**The good thing about this code is that it gives good results not only with this image, but also with all the images that I tested.**

I hope it helps anyone who had the same problem.