# How to remove watermark from text document using openCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, watermark

[image]

I am new to OpenCV, I need help removing the watermark from this image, I tried using inpaint but I want a more automated way of feature mapping and inpainting, pls help me with it.

Comment: please check the link and your may be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792812/how-to-remove-watermark-background-in-image-python

Comment: @AAYUSHLAKHANI Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63088442/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all your images are like this and have a watermark as shown in the question having a light gray watermark then a simple thresholding operation will work.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('watermark.jpg')
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('Result', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Result]

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, but in doing this, some of the characters I want to keep are losing thickness. Is there any way to subtract just the watermark from the system without losing any other information?