# Removing transparent watermark from an image - python

Tags: python, image, opencv, transparency, watermark

I am trying to remove a transparent watermark from an image.

Here is my sample image:

[image]

I would like to remove the text "Watermark" from the image. As you can see, the text is transparent. So I would like to replace that text to the original background.

Something like this would be my desired output:

[image]

I tried some examples (I am currently using cv2, if other libraries can solve the problem please also recommend), but none of them where near from succeeding. I know the way to go would be to have a mask (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811122/remove-logo-watermark-given-locations-from-an-image-using-python-opencv-deep-lea/55811304#55811304) post), but they all already have masked images, but I don't.

Here is what I tried to do to have a mask, I turned down the saturation to black and white, and created an image "imagemask.jpg", then tried going through the pixels with a `for` loop:

```
mask = cv2.imread('imagemask.jpg')
new = []
rows, cols, _ = mask.shape
for i in range(rows):
    new.append([])
    #print(i)
    for j in range(cols):
        k = img[i, j]
        #print(k)
        if all(x in range(110, 130) for x in k):
            new[-1].append((255, 255, 255))
        else:
            new[-1].append((0, 0, 0))

cv2.imwrite('finalmask.jpg', np.array(new))
```

Then after that wanted to use the code for the mask, but I realized the "finalmask.jpg" is a complete mess... so I didn't try using the code for the mask.

Is this actually possible? I have been trying for around 3 hours but receiving no luck...

Comment: Why would you do something that falls in "illegal" territory unless the images belong to you. Watermarking is done precisely for that reason so that nobody can steal them.

Comment: @KnightForked Well. I know what you mean. But I am just trying to this code on specific images. Also not for public use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not trivial, my friend. To add insult to injury, your image is very low-res, compressed and has a nasty glare - that won't help processing at all. Please, look at your input and set your expectations accordingly. With that said, let's try to get the best result with what we have. These are the steps I propose:

1. Try to **segment** the *watermark* text from the image
2. **Filter** the segmentation mask and try to get a binary mask as clean as possible
3. Use the text mask to **in-paint** the offending area using the input image as reference

Now, the tricky part, as you already saw, is segmenting the text. After trying out some techniques and color spaces, I found that the [`CMYK` color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) - particularly the **K channel** - offers promising results. The text is reasonably clear and we can try an `Adaptive Thresholding` on this, let's take a look:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
imagePath = "D://opencvImages//"
img = cv2.imread(imagePath+"0f5zZm.jpg")

# Store a deep copy for the inpaint operation:
originalImg = img.copy()

# Convert to float and divide by 255:
imgFloat = img.astype(np.float) / 255.

# Calculate channel K:
kChannel = 1 - np.max(imgFloat, axis=2)
```

`OpenCV` does not offer `BGR` to `CMYK` conversion directly, so I manually had to get the `K` channel using the [conversion formula](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.html). It is very straightforward. The `K` (or *Key*) channel represents pixels of the lowest intensity (black) with color white. Meaning that the text, which is almost white, will be rendered in black... This is the `K` Channel of the input:

[image]

You see how the darker pixels on the input are almost white here? That's nice, it seems to get a clear separation between the text and everything else. It's a shame that we have some big nasty glare on the right side. Anyway, the conversion involves `float` operations, so gotta be careful with `data types`. Maybe we can improve this image with a little **brightness/contrast** adjustment. Just a little bit, I'm just trying to separate more the text from that nasty glare:

```
# Apply a contrast/brightness adjustment on Channel K:
alpha = 0
beta = 1.2
adjustedK = cv2.normalize(kChannel, None, alpha, beta, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_32F)

# Convert back to uint 8:
adjustedK = (255*adjustedK).astype(np.uint8)
```

This is the adjusted image:

[image]

There's a little bit more separation between the text and the glare, it seems. Alright, let's apply an `Adaptive Thresholding` on this bad boy to get an initial segmentation mask:

```
# Adaptive Thresholding on adjusted Channel K:
windowSize = 21
windowConstant = 11
binaryImg = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(adjustedK, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, windowSize, windowConstant)
```

You see I'm using a not-so-big `windowSize` here for the thresholding? Feel free to tune out these parameters if you like. This is the binary image I get:

[image]

Yeah, there's a lot of noise. Here's what I propose to get a cleaner mask: There's some obvious blobs that are **bigger** than the text. Likewise, there are other blobs that are **smaller** than the text. Let's locate the big blobs and the small blobs and **subtract** them. The resulting image should contain the text, if we set our parameters correctly. Let's see:

```
# Get the biggest blobs on the image:
minArea = 180
bigBlobs = areaFilter(minArea, binaryImg)

# Filter the smallest blobs on the image:
minArea = 20
smallBlobs = areaFilter(minArea, binaryImg)

# Let's try to isolate the text:
textMask = smallBlobs - bigBlobs
cv2.imshow("Text Mask", textMask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here I'm using a helper function called `areaFilter`. This function returns all the blobs of an image that are above a **minimum area threshold**. I'll post the function at the end of the answer. In the meantime, check out these cool images:

Big blobs:

[image]

Filtered small blobs:

[image]

The difference between them:

[image]

Sadly, it seems that some portions of the characters didn't survive the filtering operations. That's because the intersection of the glare and the text is too much for the algorithm to get a clear separation. Something that could benefit the result of the in-painting is a subtle blur on this mask, to get rid of that compression alias. Let's apply some `Gaussian Blur` to smooth the mask a little bit:

```
# Blur the mask a little bit to get a
# smoother inpanting result:
kernelSize = (3, 3)
textMask = cv2.GaussianBlur(textMask, kernelSize, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
```

The kernel is not that big, I just want a subtle effect. This is the result:

[image]

Finally, let's apply the in-painting:

```
# Apply the inpaint method:
inpaintRadius = 10
inpaintMethod = cv2.INPAINT_TELEA
result = cv2.inpaint(originalImg, textMask, inpaintRadius, inpaintMethod)
cv2.imshow("Inpaint Result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the final result:

[image]

Well, is not that bad, considering the input image. You can try to further improve the result adjusting some values, but the reality of this life, my dude, is that the input image is not that great to begin with. Here's the `areaFilter` function:

```
def areaFilter(minArea, inputImage):

    # Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
    componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
    cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(inputImage, connectivity=4)

    # Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
    # (skip the background component at index 0)
    remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

    # Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
    # assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
    filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')

    return filteredImage
```

Comment: The problem is that my output is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2EXi.jpg, some of the characters get some parts removed, but still not working

Comment: Thanks you so much! I did it. For future readers, the way I succeeded was to crop out the watermark from the image with numpy slicing, then set a really high minimum blob value, then obviously the code removes the water mark! after that I use `PIL.Image.paste` to paste that cropped image back into the original image! Which worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @U11-Forward AH! As your input is bigger and clearer than the original image, some threshold values must be modified, like the `minArea` for both area filters. Anyway, glad I could help!