# remove watermark from document

Tags: python, image, opencv, tesseract

```
import cv2

def convert_black_white(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    # Rescaling
    # img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    (thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 128, 155, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    cv2.imwrite(path, grayImage)
    cv2.imwrite('/tmp/' + 'changed4.jpg', grayImage)

    cv2.imshow("Gray image", grayImage)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

convert_black_white("test.jpg")
```

[image]

This is my code and I attach input.
What I want to do is to remove the SAMPLE background and only get the text with it.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have the original as PDF or only this picture of it?

Comment: Do you have the input image available at a higher resolution?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125281/removing-watermark-out-of-an-image-using-opencv
This should work in your case as well!